# Excel VB - insivible work sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to open only the userform when I open the excel sheet. I used the below code but other excel also become invisible. I want to display other open excel file and only macro contained file should be disable.

```
Application.Visible = False
UserForm4.Show
```

Comment: `I used below code but other excel also become insible.` Open your file in a separate Excel Instance or open the rest of the file in separate instance :)

Answer (score 0):

If I see well what you mean, I think the best thing to do is to make your `xlsm` file an add-in. In order to do this:

1) Call the `UserForm4.Show` into the `Workbook_Open` event of your `.xlsm`;

2) Save your workbook as *Excel Add-In* (extensions: `.xla` or the newer `.xlam`);

3) Enable the add-in on Excel, so every time that a workbook is opened you can show the form and not the entire workbook, so avoiding also to let the `EXCEL.EXE` instance open (that will remain so if the `Application` is `Visible=False`, because no user would see it after closing the workbook they're working with).

Add-ins have a great power in terms of use and distribution, I suggest you to get started from [here](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fileextensions/f/xlamfile.htm) and go deeper into this very nice tool.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to the user form...

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = True
End Sub
```